# UserPasswordHasher : Expected an instance of "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface" as first argument

Tags: symfony, fixtures, password-hash

I'm trying to use UserPasswordInterface from Symfony with my fixtures. All the information of my fixtures arrives in the database but the passwords are not hashed . I get this error message when I do php `bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load :  In UserPasswordHasher.php line 41:Expected an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface" as first argument, but got "App\Entity\User"`

I already tried using this topic but I think I didn't understand what to do in my case because I have fixtures:

[Expected an instance of "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface" as first argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68164003/expected-an-instance-of-symfony-component-security-core-user-userinterface-as)

According to the terminal, the problem comes from this line in the fixtures :

`$hashedPassword = $this->hasher->hashPassword($user, $users[$u]['password']);`.

So I tried replacing it with :

`$hashedPassword = $this->hasher->hashPassword($user, $user->getPassword());`

but I get this error : `Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasher:: hashPassword() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/TE ST TECHNIQUE WAYATECH/symfony-API/src/DataFixtures/AppFixtures.php on line 7`

Thank you sincerely for your help. I hope my question has been drafted properly . Be indulgent I am a beginner and if you have an idea of ​​the solution please explain it to me. Thank you very much!!!

UserEntity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * [UniqueEntity('mail')]
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Cette valeur est obligatoire")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Cette valeur est obligatoire")
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Cette valeur est obligatoire")
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Cette valeur est obligatoire")
     * @Assert\Length(10)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Cette valeur est obligatoire")
     */
    private $role = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Cette valeur est obligatoire")
     */
    private $password;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail(string $mail): self
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTelephone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    public function setTelephone(string $telephone): self
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRole(): ?array
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    public function setRole(array $role): self
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the hashed password
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set the hashed password
     *
     * @param  string  $password  The hashed password
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setPassword(string $password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

AppFixtures

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Faker\Factory;
use App\Entity\User;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function __construct(UserPasswordHasherInterface $hasher)
    {
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {

        $faker = Factory::create();

        $roles = [
            'ROLE_USER',
            'ROLE_ADMIN',
        ];

        $users =
            [
                [
                    'firstname' => 'Jérémy',
                    'lastname' => 'Brugi',
                    'email' => 'jeremy@gmail.com',
                    'password' => 'jeremy.B84*',
                    'telephone' => '0651758859',
                    'role' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                ],
                [
                    'firstname' => 'Victor',
                    'lastname' => 'Lant',
                    'email' => 'victor@gmail.com',
                    'password' => 'victor.L84*',
                    'telephone' => '0578598516',
                    'role' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                ],
                [
                    'firstname' => 'Laure',
                    'lastname' => 'Chapert',
                    'email' => 'laure@gmail.com',
                    'password' => 'laure.C84*',
                    'telephone' => '0485976524',
                    'role' => 'ROLE_USER',
                ],
                [
                    'firstname' => 'Elise',
                    'lastname' => 'Jérémy',
                    'email' => 'elise@gmail.com',
                    'password' => 'elise.P84*',
                    'telephone' => '0685741954',
                    'role' => 'ROLE_USER',
                ],
            ];

        $userObjects = [];
        for ($u = 0; $u <=  count($users) - 1; $u++) {
            $user = new User;
            $user->setFirstName($users[$u]['firstname']);
            $user->setLastName($users[$u]['lastname']);
            $user->setTelephone($users[$u]['telephone']);
            $user->setMail($users[$u]['email']);
            $user->setRole([$users[$u]['role']]);
            $hashedPassword = $this->hasher->hashPassword($user, $users[$u]['password']);
            $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);
            $userObjects[] = $user;
            $manager->persist($user);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

security.yaml

```
security:
  enable_authenticator_manager: true
  encoders:
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
  password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: "auto"
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: auto
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
  providers:
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: app_user_provider

      # activate different ways to authenticate
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
      # switch_user: true

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
  security:
    password_hashers:
      # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
      # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
      # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
      # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
      Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
        algorithm: auto
        cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
        time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
        memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

The first error tells that your User class has to implement the `UserInterface` interface. I think reading the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-user) as to how implementing a user works would be a good starting point :) If you have any more questions, please let me know.

PS. Your first post looks good!

```php
/**
 * [UniqueEntity('mail')]
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I already tried it but I get many errors like this : (  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'UNIQ  
  _8D93D649E7927C74' ) when I do migration then migrate  it ...

Comment: You could try truncating your table, if that is possible, and then retry the migrate. The integrity constraint is probably about the data in your existing database. If not, please update your question and let me know.

Comment: I deleted my user table and tried to make a migrations:migrate .. But I still get an error "Duplicate Key name "UNIQ__(some letters and numbers)"